# C# Application and Access database works on some computers

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2010

I made a program which uses an access database. It works fine on my own computer.
Then it did not work on another comp, because it could not find the database file. 
So I changed the App.config filepath and Settings.Designer.cs (I don't if these are the correct lines to edit but with these changes the program worked on one computer). Then the app started working.

Next I tested the program on third computer.
But the program did not work because it did not find the database file.

I have changed the database filepath from those 2 config files above to C:\Temp\ as testing purposes and all computers have the database file in that folder.

The working computers have Windows 7 and the one where the database doesn't work is running Windows 8.

What causes this behaviour? Thanks! And if i adited the wrong filepaths, please let me know. The ideal solution would be that if I move the program to another computer, it would search the database from the programfolder.

**Additional information:**

This is the edited line from Settings.Designer.cs where I only edited that "C:\Temp\":

```
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"C:\\Temp\\database.accdb\"")]
    public string HRSConnectionString1 {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["HRSConnectionString1"]));
        }
```

There is also one line which is automatically generated:

```
     [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\database.accdb;OLE DB Se" +
        "rvices=-13")]
    public string HRSConnectionString {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["HRSConnectionString"]));
        }
```

And these are the lines from App.config:

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="HRS.Properties.Settings.HRSConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\database.accdb;OLE DB Services=-13"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    <add name="HRS.Properties.Settings.HRSConnectionString1" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=&quot;C:\Temp\database.accdb&quot;"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Can you possibly add more details, like maybe show some lines of the config files to see?

Answer (score 0):

can you try with data sources (ODBC)? Start - > administrative tools - > Data Sources(ODBC)

[help link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca6axakh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[image]

Comment: Non-working computer had 32-bit and 64-bit data sources in administrative tools. There were Access driver and user data sources in both data sources. Environment was 64bit.

At my computer (Win7 64bit), where the program works is only one data sources to start from administrative tools and there is MS Access database in user data sources, but there is no MS Access driver in drivers tab.

In visual studio 2012 I also tried to change few connection string in program properties and modified the connection but still it does not work...